# Search Engine listing like the provided screenshot

Tags: search, seo

My question is about Search Engine Result pages, if your site is the first search engine result, many site's search results show the page listing like this as is [this screenshot](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/638421-6122011113802pm.png).

So, is there a procedure to follow so I can achieve the same effect for my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, those are automatically generated by Google. You can read more details on the [Google Webmaster page about Sitelinks](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334).

Answer (score 0):

Those are completely generated automatically by GOOGLE

Google Doesn't Say How to Get Sitelinks

The workings of many Google algorithms, including Sitelinks, are kept secret to discourage people from manipulating the rankings, but we can still look at examples and try to understand where Sitelinks come from. I've worked on a number of sites with Sitelinks, and these sites are similar in the following ways:

```
* Site ranks first for the keyword(s) that generate the Sitelinks listing
* Easily spiderable, structured navigation
* Fairly high natural search traffic
* High click through rates from the search results page
* Useful outbound links
* Inbound links from high quality sites
* Site age is several years or older
```

Answer (score 0):

Sitelinks generally appear when a site is considered to be the main authority on a particular keyword, in short an old site with lots of links with the keyword anchor text is likely to get sitelinks.
I've found that, as stated above, having clear navigation helps. Also, it appears that the Google bot has particular support for media wiki, automatically pulling the TOC out into the results.
You can get more information about your own site links by logging into google webmaster tools.